# Distributed cache service is not enabled in this deployment

Tags: distributedcache, services

In the Sharepoint Health Report, I'm getting an error saying that 'Distributed cache service is not enabled in this deployment.' The resolution seems simple enough: `Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance` in PowerShell. HOWEVER, when I go to: `CA>Application Management>Manage Services on Server`, I see that Distributed Cache is already started. I'm not sure what the disconnect is. How can it be both running and not running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the entry from the Health Analyzer report and see if it comes back. Sometimes these reports do not auto-clear.

Comment: that was the problem - now to find out WHY they don't auto-clear